# Why do I get this error : C2143 syntax error: missing ',' before '&'?

Tags: c++

Everything was going well until I added the drow function into Renderer.h file

```cpp
void Drow(const VertexArray& va, const IndexBuffer& ib, const Shader& shader)const;
```

Renderer.h :

```cpp
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include"Shader.h"
#include"VertexArray.h"
#include"IndexBuffer.h"


#define ASSERT(x) if(!(x))__debugbreak();
#define GLCall(x) GLClearError();\
    x;\
    ASSERT(GLlogCall(#x, __FILE__, __LINE__))

/*function to clear all last errors in opengl*/
void GLClearError();

/*function to print all errors */
bool GLlogCall(const char* function, const char* file, int line);

class Renderer {
public:
    void clear()const;
    void Drow(const VertexArray& va, const IndexBuffer& ib, const Shader& shader)const;

};
```

When I try to build it I get this error in visual studio 2015 :

```
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ',' before '&'
```

and this one

```
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

I could not figure out why !

Comment: `Drow` or `Draw`?

Comment: Are you sure that `VertexArray`, `IndexBuffer` and `Shader` are all defined?

Comment: yes,These are classes that I have previously created @ tadman

Comment: It might be that either your `VertexArray`, `IndexBuffer` or `Shader` header files are including this file and you have circular dependencies. Since you're only using references, you can just forward declare these types.

Comment: How can I advertise these types?
Can you explain it? I tried to do this ```#include <GL\glew.h>
class Shader;
class VertexArray;
class IndexBuffer;``` instead of include them but it did not make a difference @Tas

Comment: BTW, you don't have to include headers in this case. You can use forward declaration and include headers to cpp file. It'll reduce headers dependency.

Comment: Yep that looks fine, assuming those classes were declare with `class` and not `struct`. Once forward declared you can remove the `#include <Shader.h>` etc

Comment: Thank you all for your help, it has come back to work again  ^__^

Comment: If you can qualify what you did to fix it as a self-answer that'd help explain better to other people in the same jam, and possibly even yourself in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was that  VertexArray, IndexBuffer or Shader header files were including Rendered.h file so I had circular dependencies like this :

Renderer.h

```cpp
#include"Shader.h"
#include"VertexBuffer.h"
#include"IndexBuffer.h"

class Renderer{
public:
// some code
    void Drow(const VertexArray& va, const IndexBuffer& ib, const Shader& shader)const;
}
```

and Shader.h ,VertexBuffer.h,IndexBuffer.h files have this code:

```cpp
#include"Renderer.h"
class className{
//  code
}
```

so I used the forward declaration and included the headers to cpp file and files have become this way
Renderer.h

```cpp
#include <GL\glew.h>

class Shader.h;
class VertexBuffer.h;
class IndexBuffer.h;

class Renderer{

public:

//  code
    void Drow(const VertexArray& va, const IndexBuffer& ib, const Shader& shader)const;
}
```

Renderer.cpp

```cpp
#include "Renderer.h"
#include<iostream>

#include"Shader.h"
#include"VertexArray.h"
#include"IndexBuffer.h"

// the rest of code
```

and Shader.h ,VertexBuffer.h,IndexBuffer.h files have this code:

```cpp
//still have
#include "Renderer.h"
class className{
//  code
}
```